# Metadata filter in Essbase not working

Tags: essbase

I have a BSO cube and it's Org hierarchy is set like below:

Org:

```
totalUS    
          US  
             US retail  
             Us non retail  
  A1  
  B1  
  C1  
  D1  
    D_001
```

the user group should only see data for @IDescendants(US non retail) and Idescendants(D1).The user wants totalus hidden too.
My Maxl script is:

grant read on database 'Test'.'Test' to group 'Test';
   create or replace filter 'Test'.'Test'.'MetaTest' 
   meta_read on '@IDESCENDANTS ("US non retail"),@IDESCENDANTS("D1")' ;
   grant filter 'Test'.'Test'.'MetaTest' to group 'Test';

Still my Smart view pull shows data and member name for totalus,totalus is sibling of A1,B1,C1,D1.
Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your filter to disallow access to the `@IDESCENDANTS("TotalUS")` and then have the metaread. Just because the metaread focuses on a different hierarchy doesn't mean that you've addressed the other elements in the hierarchy, which is what you need to do. The Essbase admin guide talks about some of the fundamentals of filters, including this.

Comment: So do I need to have none access to idescendatnt of Totalus and in same filter have metaread?

Comment: Yes. Always start by denying the things you don't want them to have, then adding back in more specific items.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please don't forget to update/mark the Stack Overflow answer, thanks.